# Compute DP[n][m] faster

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given: `DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j] + DP[i-1][j-1]*C[i]`

I want to calculate DP[n][m]. I know I can compute all the DP[][] values, but I want a solution for typically larger N & M( upto 45000 ). 
Is there any way  to do it faster ?

Comment: I think you should better post the original problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Indeed! Is this some kind of Knapsack problem?

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity-wise I don't think you can get much better without any additional information. However, you can compute the matrix row by row, leading to an improved space efficiency of O(m) instead of Ω(N * M):

```
current_row = [X, 0, ...]
prev_row = [0,0,...]
for i := 1 to n:
  copy current_row to prev_row
  # TODO compute current_row[0], recurrence not given
  for j := 1 to i:
    current_row[j] = prev_row[j-1] + C*prev_row[j]
```

`DP[n][m]` will correspond to `current_row[m]` in the end

Answer (score 0):

I totally second the answer of Niklas B. in the aspect that the implementation cannot be made faster complexity-wise, however you could use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) instead of 'true' dynamic programming. Although it does not improve the worst-case complexity, it potentially results in calculation of fewer intermediate values.

Comment: Not really, because all values of the lower diagonal of the matrix are needed.